# How do I copy a HttpRequest to another web service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, httpwebrequest, web

I have two identical web services currently installed on the same PC for testing purposes. A request that is received by the first service, is suposed go to the second one as well. My intention was to do this using a HttpModule. I handle the request during application.BeginRequest.

```
public void AsyncForwardRequest(HttpRequest request)
{
    try
    {
        // Prepare web request...
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(WSaddress);

        req.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        req.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", request.Headers["SOAPAction"]);
        req.ContentType = request.Headers["Content-Type"];
        req.Accept = request.Headers["Accept"];
        req.Method = request.HttpMethod;

        // Send the data.
        long posStream = request.InputStream.Position;
        long len = request.InputStream.Length;
        byte[] buff = new byte[len];
        request.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        if (len < int.MaxValue && request.InputStream.Read(buff, 0, (int)len) > 0)
        {
            using (Stream stm = req.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stm.Write(buff, 0, (int)len);
            }

            request.InputStream.Position = posStream;
            DebugOutputStream(request.InputStream);
            request.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            IAsyncResult result = (IAsyncResult)req.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(RespCallback), req);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        App.Error2(String.Format("RequestDuplicatorModule - BeginRequest; ERROR begin request: {0}", ex.Message), ex);
    }

private static void RespCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
{
    try
    {
        // State of request is asynchronous.
        var req = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
        WebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);

        Stream responseStream = resp.GetResponseStream();
        System.IO.Stream stream = responseStream;
        Byte[] arr = new Byte[1024 * 100];
        stream.Read(arr, 0, 1024 * 100);
        if (arr.Length > 0)
        {
            string body = (new ASCIIEncoding()).GetString(arr);
            Debug.Print(body);
        }
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        App.Error2(String.Format("RequestDuplicatorModule - BeginRequest; ERROR begin request: {0}", ex.Message), ex);
    }

}
```

This (HttpWebResponse)req.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult) throws an exception: 500 Internal Server Error and fails. The original request goes through fine.

request.InnerStream:
    ...

Does this have anything to do with the web service addresses being different? In my case they're:
http://localhost/WS/service.asmx
http://localhost/WS_replicate/service.asmx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to modify the AsyncForwardRequest method so that I can actually edit the SoapEnvelope itself:

```
string buffString = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buff);

using (Stream stm = req.GetRequestStream())
{
    bool stmIsReadable = stm.CanRead;  //false, stream is not readable, how to get
                                       //around this?
                                       //solution: read Byte Array into a String,
                                       //modify <wsa:to>, write String back into a
                                       //Buffer, write Buffer to Stream

    buffString = buffString.Replace("http://localhost/WS/Service.asmx", WSaddress);

    //write modded string to buff
    buff = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(buffString);

    stm.Write(buff, 0, (int)buff.Length);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would at least implement this, to be able to read the content of a httpwebrequest that has a status 500:

```
catch (WebException ex)
{
    HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
    Stream dataStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();

    if (dataStream != null)
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        response = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Not answering your question though, i would suggest having a simple amsx that reads the request, and posts the request to the two different web services. If you need some code for that let me know.

Additional advantages would be that the asmx will be easier to support for the developer as well as the one dealing with the deployment. You could add configuration options to make the actual url's dynamic.

Comment: Good idea! Now I know that my assumption was correct. The problem is in the Wsa:To field which of course doesn't point to the correct URI. In this case, it should be pointing to the second asmx. Now I have to figure out how to change that for the Async request.

Comment: Here is the exception itself:  The <wsa:To> header must match the actor URI value of the web service. The actor URI value can be explicitly specified using SoapActorAttribute on the ASMX class. In the absence of the attribute, the actor URI is assumed to be equal to the HTTP Request Url of the incoming message. The <To> header received contained "http://localhost/WS/Service.asmx" while the receiver is expecting "http://localhost/ws_replicate/service.asmx".

Comment: I think I solved this but it might not be the best solution. In the WS_Replicate/Service.cs I added [Microsoft.Web.Services3.Messaging.SoapActor("*")] to avoid having the Request URI compared to the Wsa:To field. The replication now works. I would still very much like to hear other opinions on improving this solution.